# select ids with particular entries on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies if this exists in another question but I'm unable to locate it. Say I have a table

```
ID   Type
1     A
1     A
4     A
1     A
1     A
2     A
2     B
3     A
3     A
3     B
4     A
1     A
4     A
```

I want to select the ids that only have entry 'A' in the Type column for all their row entries. Expected output should be:

```
ID
1
4
```

I attempted to do this

```
select id 
from table 
order by id 
having Type = 'A'
```

but not getting expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregation is one approach, but your `HAVING` clause needs to change:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(Type) = 'A' AND MIN(Type) = MAX(Type);  -- sargable HAVING clause
```

### Demo

The `MIN`/`MAX` equality check in the `HAVING` clause ensures that any given matching `ID` has only one value across the entire table.  The first `MIN` assertion ensures that this one value is `A`.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use a conditional aggregate in the `HAVING`:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT(CASE [Type] WHEN 'A' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) = 0
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT T.ID
  FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
 GROUP BY T.ID
  HAVING MAX(T.TYPE)='A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this query

```
SELECT id 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 1 AND MAX(type) = 'A'
ORDER BY id;
```